# Kotlin Map with If statement

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Trying to write some Functional code and use map - maybe filter too? - to replace something like:

```
for (something in somethingList) {
    if (something.value == someOtherThing.value)
        result = true
}
```

With something more functional like found here: https://grokonez.com/kotlin/kotlin-filter-map-examples

But I don't want to return a new map I want to set `result` to the condition of `something.value == someOtherThing.value` being true or not.

But I'm getting lost in my neophyte world of Functional Kotlin.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/any.html) for this purpose.

```kotlin
val result = somethingList.any { it.value == someOtherThing.value }
```